# Probability that he answered a question correctly and knew the answer - is my solution correct?

Tags: probability

A student is taking a multiple-choice test. Given a question, the student either knows
the answer, in which case he answers correctly, or he does not know the answer, in
which case he guesses the answer randomly. Every question has five possible answers.
Assume that the student knows the correct answer to a question in 70% of all cases.
Having observed that the student answered a given question correctly, what is the
probability that he really knew the answer.

So, based on the information provided we have:

Event A: He knows the answer

> P(A)=0.7

Event B: He doesn't know the answer

> P(B)=0.3

Event C: He didn't know the answer and he answers a question correct (of which the probability is 0.2 since each question has 5 possible answer).

> P(C)=0.3x0.2=0.06

Event D: He answers a question correct. So basically here I am summing up the previous probabilities, aka: P(A)+P(C) = 0.7 + 0.06 = 0.76

> Now, given event D, the probability that A occured if D happened.
>
> (A|D) = P(D|A)xP(A)$\frac{P(D|A)*P(A)}{P(D)}=\frac{1*0.7}{0.76}=0.92$

Is this solution correct or did I mess something up? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems correct to me!

Comment: Both method and result look good.

Comment: Thank you both! Much appreciated! :)